# Building a response in Dialogflow using multiple responses

Tags: dialogflow-es

Please excuse me if this is a really basic question - I'm very much still learning, and I just cannot find a solution.

I'm trying to use the standard basic text responses in Dialogflow, which from what I understand, should work.

What I want to do, is have a set statement (Okay, let's see what I can find), then a random pick from a list, then another set statement, essentially stacking the responses in Dialogflow (see screenshot).

It works absolutely fine in Dialogflow's test console - however, it doesn't do what I want when I take it into the Google action simulator.

Have I made a stupid error, missed a toggle switch somewhere, or am I trying to do something unsupported?

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 0):

To surface text responses defined in Dialogflow's default response tab go to the Google Assistant response tab and turn on the switch that says "Use response from the DEFAULT tab as the first response.":

[image]